# Regular wrong regular expression, not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

please i want to validate the inputs from a user, the format for the inputs would be: 3 uppercase characters, 3 integer numbers, an optional space, a -, an optional space, either a 'LAB or ((EN or ENLH) with 1 interger number ranging from a [1-9]).

The regex i wrote is

```
/\D{3}\d{3}\s?-\s?(LAB|(EN(LH)?\d{1}))/
```

am finding it difficult to stop **inputs after the LAB** so that when **EEE333 - LAB1** is inputed it becomes invalid.

Comment: If the input is to end at the end if line, then put a `$` at the end of your regex.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need @ lurker 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to prevent LAB1 at the end, use an end of line anchor `$` in your regex test:
`/\D{3}\d{3}\s?-\s?(LAB|(EN(LH)?\d{1}))$/`

If you are trying to require exactly one digit at the end of the acceptable strings, move the single digit match outside of the optional groups:
`/\D{3}\d{3}\s?-\s?(LAB|(EN(LH)?))\d{1}$/`

Answer (score 1):

**I have wrote for you the following regular expression:**

*[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}\s?-\s?(?:LAB|(?:EN|LH))[1-9]{1}*

The regex works a follows:

> ```
> [A-Z]{3}
> ```
>
> ***MATCH EXACTLY THREE UPPERCASE CHARACTERS RANGING FROM A TO Z***
>
> ```
> [0-9]{3}
> ```
>
> ***MATCH EXACTLY THREE NUMBERS RANGING FROM 0 TO 9***
>
> ```
> \s?\-\s?
> ```
>
> ***MATCH a space (optional) or a '-' (required) or a space (optional)***
>
> ```
> (?:LAB|(?:EN|LH))
> ```
>
> ***MATCH 'LAB' OR ('EN' OR 'LH')
> ?: omits capturing LAB OR EN OR LH***
>
> ```
> [1-9]{1}
> ```
>
> ***MATCH EXACTLY ONE NUMBERS RANGING FROM 1 TO 9***

Answer (score 1):

You could place your regex between word boundaries `\b`. 
You start your regex with `\D` which is any character that is not a digit. That would for example also match `$%^`. You could use `[A-Z]`.

You use `\d{1}` which is a shorhand for `[0-9]`, but you want to match a digit between 1 and 9 `[1-9]`. You could also omit the `{1}`.

Maybe this updated will work for you?

[`\b[A-Z]{3}\d{3} ?- ?(?:LAB|(?:EN(?:LH)?[1-9]))\b`](http://rubular.com/r/1966gQZv0Z)

**Explanation**

- A word boundary `\b`
- Match 3 uppercase characters `[A-Z]{3}`
- Match 3 digits `\d{3}`
- Match an optional whitespace, a hyphen and another optional whitespace `?- ?`
- A non capturing group which for example matches LAB or EN EN1 or ENLH or ENLH9  `(?:EN(?:LH)?[1-9]))`
- A word boundary `\b`

Comment: Thanks a lot how then do you write a regex for a number ringing from 1-12 @the fourth bird

Comment: @lilfancy You could take a look at [numeric ranges](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html). A regex like for example [`\b([1-9]|1[0-2])\b`](http://rubular.com/r/TcdudOCJ0s)